# RESTAPI OrientDB Create document Base64 encoding issue

Tags: rest, orientdb

I try to post a simple document to my OrientDB server (v2.2.22) by using the REST API

But I recieve a 500, here's the body that I send,

```
{
  "@class": "Student",
  "firstName": "Gilles",
  "lastName": "Bodart",
  "dateOfBirth": "1992-04-14",
  "sexe": "M"
}
```

And here's the response

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 500,
            "reason": 500,
            "content": "com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Error on unmarshalling JSON content for record: \"@class\":\"Student\",\"firstName\":\"Benjamin\",\"lastName\":\"Leroy\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"1992-10-31\",\"sexe\":\"M\"\r\n\tDB name=\"Memoire\"\r\n--> com.orientechnologies.common.io.OIOException: Bad Base64 input character decimal 45 in array position 4"
        }
    ]
}
```

It seems to be an issue wirh the date, but I send it like a String.

In my schema, it's typed Custom I don't relly know why but I can't modify it to String

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To try you case I used Postman and it works for me, I only added a couple of lines:

```
{"transaction": false , "operations":[
    { "type": "c",
      "record" : {
            "@class" : "Student",
            "firstName": "Gilles",
            "lastName": "Bodart",
            "dateOfBirth": "1992-04-14",
            "sexe": "M"
        }
    }
]}
```

this is the request:

[image]

and this is what I get:

[image]

as you can see the dateOfBirth type is STRING

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Thanks for this solution, indeed I removed the property that was of type CUSTOM, I don't know why... But this solution also work !